# How can a child browser window change the window's properties?

Tags: javascript, windows, browser

I'm working with a software package that creates Flash panorama .swf's. The package allows the creation of hotspots in the pano. You can specify the URL and the Target of the hotspot, so if you click on the hotspot it launches the URL in _blank, _self, etc.
However, the package doesn't allow you to specify the attributes of the window.

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way for the child window (once the swf opens it), to control it's own window attributes via Javascript.

I want to be able to control the size of the window and hide the address bar, status bar, etc.

One other issue that I need to deal with is this...I don't want the child window to open in a tab, but in a new smaller window...the only way that I've done this in the past is if the parent opens the child window and specify the size and that there are no menu bars and address bars. I'm not sure how to do that ***from*** the child window.

Answer (score 1):

> want to be able to control the size of the window and hide the address bar, status bar, etc.

You can maybe use [`window.resizeTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.resizeTo) / [`window.resizeBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.resizeBy) to resize the window. I'm saying "maybe" because some browsers will allow this only for windows opened through `window.open()`.

You will not be able to get rid of the address bar and status bar in modern browsers any more for security reasons.

> One other issue that I need to deal with is this...I don't want the child window to open in a tab, but in a new smaller window...the only way that I've done this in the past is if the parent opens the child window and specify the size and that there are no menu bars and address bars. I'm not sure how to do that from the child window.

This would amount to turning a "normal" window into a `window.open` popup window - I don't think that can be done at all.

Sadly, dealing with pop-up windows has become very restrictive because it has been abused so much.